Beecrowd 2035 50% error My code wont work with big inputs
Context:

Argentina's rugby is currently in one of its best moments of all time.
Recently the under-18 and under-21 national teams qualified for their
corresponding world cups, so the coaches of both teams have asked the
Incredible Commission for the Production of Clothing (ICPC) to provide
the t-shirts for these events. Each team is formed by N players, but
because the two world cups do not take place simultaneously it was
agreed that the ICPC would provide only N t-shirts, to be used by both
teams.
For this reason, the t-shirts must be a valid set of clothing for both
teams. The rules of the rugby world cups state that each player must
go in the field with a t-shirt imprinted with a unique number, along
with a prefix of the player's surname, not necessarily unique. This
includes boundary cases such as a t-shirt with no surname prefix (that
is, a prefix of length 0) and a t-shirt with a complete surname.
The experts of ICPC immediately realized that they could simply
provide N t-shirts with only numbers and no surnames on them, and each
of them would be a valid t-shirt to be used by any player of any of
the two teams. However, the coaches would rather have the t-shirts
with the longest possible prefixes, of course without violating world
cup rules, because this way it's easier for them to identify the
players while the matches are taking place.
Your task is to help the ICPC finding the maximum amount of letters
that can be imprinted on a set of N t-shirts, so that this set is a
valid clothing set for both teams. For example, if we have N = 3
players, the under-18 team is composed of "PEREZ", "GONZALEZ" and
"LOPEZ", whereas the under-21 team is composed of "GARCIA", "PERALTA"
and "RODRIGUEZ", the optimal choice consists in having one t-shirt
with the 1-letter prefix "G" (to be used by "GONZALEZ" and "GARCIA"),
anotherone with the 3-letter prefix"PER" (to be used by "PEREZ" and
"PERALTA"), and the third t-shirt with a 0-letter prefix (to be used
by"LOPEZ" and "RODRIGUEZ"). This way, the answer in this case would be
1+3+0=4.
Input
Each test case is described using three lines. The first line contains
a single integer number N, indicating the number of players in each of
the two teams (1 ≤ N ≤ 104). The second line contains the surnames of
the N players in the under-18 team, whereas the third line contains
the surnames of the N players in the under-21 team. Each surname is a
non-empty string of at most 100 uppercase letters. In each test case
the total number of characters in the 2N surnames is at most 105, and
two or more players of the same or different teams may have the same
surname.
The end of the input is indicated by a line containing the number -1.
Output
For each test case, you should print a single line containing an
integer number, representing the maximum number of letters that can be
imprinted on a set of N valid t-shirts to be used by both teams as
explained in the problem statement.

My code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    
    while (scanf("%d", &N) && N != -1) {
        int total_letters = 0;

        // Dynamically allocating an array of strings for the teams
        char ***teams = (char ***)malloc(2 * sizeof(char **));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            teams[i] = (char **)malloc(N * sizeof(char *));
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                teams[i][j] = (char *)malloc(101 * sizeof(char)); // Allocates 101 characters for each name
            }
        }

        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                scanf("%100s", teams[i][j]); 
            }
        }

        // Comparison between players of team 0 and players of team 1
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int max_prefix = 0; 

            // Compare player i of team 0 with all players of team 1
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int current_prefix = 0; 
                
                // Compare character by character
                for (int k = 0; teams[0][i][k] != '\0' && teams[1][j][k] != '\0'; k++) {
                    if (teams[0][i][k] == teams[1][j][k]) {
                        current_prefix++; // Increment the length of the prefix
                    } else {
                        break; // Stop when a difference is found
                    }
                }

                // Update the longest common prefix found for player i of team 0
                if (current_prefix > max_prefix) {
                    max_prefix = current_prefix;
                }
            }

            // Accumulate the longest prefix found for player i
            total_letters += max_prefix;
        }

        // Print the total number of letters that can be printed on the shirts
        printf("%d\n", total_letters);

        // Free the allocated memory
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                free(teams[i][j]); // Free each string
            }
            free(teams[i]); // Free the array of strings
        }
        free(teams); // Free the main array
    }

    return 0;
}


Well, my code runs as it's supposed to with lower inputs, like:
Input:3
PEREZ GONZALEZ LOPEZ
GARCIA PERALTA RODRIGUEZ
Output:4

This output is correct according to the Beecrowd website.
However, when it comes to larger inputs, it becomes a mess and loses its precision.
Input:11
BABBABAABAABBAABABBBBAABABBAAAABABBBBBBBAAAABAA ABB BBBBBABAABAABBAABBAAABBABBBBABBBBBBBBBAABAAAABABABAABAABBBABBBAABABBAAAABBAABABBABABBBAB BABBAAABBBBABAAAABBBBBBBABAAAAABBABBAAAAAABBAABAAABABBBBAAAAABAABAAABBABBABAABA BABBBBBBBABBBAAAABBAAABABABABBAAAAABBAABAABABABAABABBABAAAABBBBBAB BBBBAAABBBBA BBBB ABBABBABABAAAAABAABABBABABBBBBAABABAABBAAABABBAABAAABBBAAABBABBBBAAABAAABAAABB BAABAABAAAAAABBABBAAABABBABAABBBABABABABBBABAAAABABBBAAAABBABAABBBBBABAAAABABABBABBB ABBBBAAABABABABBAABBAAABBBAABABBAABABABABBBABBABABA ABBBAABBBABBAAABAABBBABAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAABBBABBBBBAAAAABAABA
BBABABBBAABABBAABBBBAABBAAABABAB BABAAABBBAAABABBABBBBAAAAABBAAABAAAABBBAABAABBBAABAABA AAAAAAAAAAABBAABBBBABBABABBAAABAABBBBBBABBABBABAABABBAABBBAAAABBABAAABABABBABBBABAAAABBAAB BAAAAAABAABBABBABAAAAAAABAABBBBAABABAAAAAABABABBAABABBABAAAABAABAABBAABBAABABABAAABBAABBA BABBAAAAAAAAABABBBAABBBBAAABBABABAABABBBBABAABAABBABBBAAAAAABBABABBBABB AABABBABBABBBBABABBABABABBABABBBAAAAABBBBBBABBAAABAAABAAAAAABBBABABBBBABABBBBBBABABBABAAABABB BBABBAAABBAAABBBBABBBBBAAABABABAAABBABBBBBBABAAABABAAABAABABAAAABABAABABAAABA AABBBBABBAAABBABABABABABBBABBAABBBBABBBBBABBA AABABAAAABBABBAAAA AABBBBBBBBBBAAABBBABBBAABBBBBBBAABBBBBBABBB ABBABABABAABBBBBBABABBBABABA
Output:39

This output is incorrect according to the Udebug website (Beecrowd's debug site); it should be 25. I have no idea why this is happening.

Is this a new question from a new user? Or is it a re-post of BEECROWD 2035?

Its a new question from a new user

Have you tried single-stepping with a debugger?  This is an essential skill for C programming, so if you don't yet know how to use a debugger, I'd make that your top priority.

These challenge sites are there for you to solve. If I could solve it, I would post my answer directly to that site. Do you have a specific question about C? Always develop your solution locally, so that you can use a debugger, set up specific test cases, etc.

Can you figure out why 25 is the correct result for that input? That should help you figure out where your program is going wrong.

Consider the following sample input.
2
PERDOMO PEREZ
PERALTA RUIZ

Your program outputs 6, because each of the two players PERDOMO and PEREZ from team 0 has a 3-character common prefix with a player from team 1, namely PERALTA in each case.  So you're proposing that the clothing set could consist of two shirts that both say PER.  That would be fine for team 0, but not for team 1,  because RUIZ can't wear either of those shirts.  The correct answer would be 3: one shirt with PER and one that is blank.
So your algorithm is too simple.  If you're going to try to "match" each player on team 0 with a player on team 1 who shares a common prefix, you have to ensure that two team 0 players don't both match with the same team 1 player.
I leave it to you to work out a new algorithm that solves the problem correctly, because that's the point of the contest, after all.

I had a feeling it had something to do with duplicate matches. But the input that produces the erroneous result was so random that it was hard to see it.
